# Is there any way to paste from a data only the same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming that I have a self-created data set like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['A','B'],[21,22],['B','C'],[25,26]], columns=['a1','a2'])
```

```
a1  a2
A   B
1   None
B   C
2   None
```

then I use the data.dropna function to separate the rows of text for data processing in excel:

```
dropdf=data.dropna(axis=0, subset=['a2'])
```

```
a1  a2
A   B
B   C
```

After processing I have an extra column called 'a3' like this

```
a1  a2  a3
A   B   C
B   C   D
```

What I want here is how to copy and paste only these lines back into 'data' and ignore the lines that were drop at 'dropdf' while keeping the line order.

Dataframe that i want to be:

```
a1  a2   a3
A   B    C
1   None None
B   C    D
2   None None
```

Is there any way to paste from a data only the same columns

Comment: Your examples don't really make sense, the provided output of your commands is not what the commands are doing, please be clear in the inputs and output and the logic. As of now, it looks like a simple `merge`